# Send message to all users connected to router warning about reboot

Tags: wireless-networking, router, messaging

I was curious if there was a way to send a message to all the computers connected to the router, specifically the message "Rebooting router in X minutes. Save any online work."

I have an ASUS RT-AC66U router if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Such a capability is not part of the [IEEE 802.11 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11) used for [WiFi networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) nor is it part of [IEEE 802.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.3) wired networking protocols for [Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet), so it doesn't matter what router you are using. The only way for you to do something like that would be if you and everyone accessing the router were using some program, e.g., a chat or other messaging program, that would allow you to send messages to everyone running that program who might be connected to your router.

Comment: @GiantDwarf  well you don't ask for a networking standard, you seem to have the idea of sending the message "manually" rather than the router doing it automatically. i've seen windows machines about 15 years ago with that feature, I don't recall the  command  but no doubt there are still many ways native to windows  "net send" maybe https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_send.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: @barlop, Windows XP supported the [Windows Messenger Service](http://support.moonpoint.com/security/spyware/MS-Antispyware/netbios-messenger-service.html) with the [net send](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_send.mspx?mfr=true) command. You could even use the service for communicating with systems on the Internet, so spammers used it as well and Microsoft disabled the service by default in Windows XP SP2. E.g., see [Messenger Service window that contains an Internet advertisement appears](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/330904).